# Twitter app for Windows 8

Tags: windows, twitter

I'm searching for a good Twitter application for Windows 8.

Requirements:

- Runnable under Microsoft Windows 8 (obviously ;-))
- Ideally runnable on Windows 10 too, as it will be released soon
- Aware of multiple accounts (whether if I need to change the current user scope or if I'm able to select which I want to use for the next tweet)
- Show all Twitter related stuff like mentions, messages, etc.
- Metro awareness is nice to have
- Ideally actively developed, as I won't change the application after the next API change

Answer (score 1):

## The Tweetdeck interface to Twitter

It is available at tweetdeck.twitter.com, and does everything you've asked for:

#### Runnable under Microsoft Windows 8

**Yes**, works in any modern browser on Windows 8

#### Ideally runnable on Windows 10 too

**Yes**, works in any modern browser on Windows 10

#### Aware of multiple accounts (whether if I need to change the current user scope or if I'm able to select which I want to use for the next tweet)

**Yes**, you can have columns for multiple accounts, choose which accounts you tweet from, which you reply from, which you DM from, which you Follow from.

#### Show all Twitter related stuff like mentions, messages, etc.

**Yes**, you can have columns for each of those

#### Metro awareness is nice to have

**Yes**, If you have a metro browser, it should work in that. It works in the Edge browser.

#### Ideally actively developed, as I won't change the application after the next API change

**Yes**, it's actively maintained and developed by Twitter